# Scala specs2 nested-in with context

Tags: scala, specs2

I am trying to run some tests in Scala using specs2, but I am having some problems with some test cases not being executed.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate my problem.

BaseSpec.scala

```
package foo

import org.specs2.mutable._

trait BaseSpec extends Specification {
  println("global init")
  trait BeforeAfterScope extends BeforeAfter {
    def before = println("before")
    def after = println("after")
  }
}
```

FooSpec.scala

```
package foo

import org.specs2.mutable._

class FooSpec extends BaseSpec {
  "foo" should {
    "run specs" in new BeforeAfterScope {
      "should fail" in {
        true must beFalse
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect the test to fail, however it seems that the case "should fail" in the nested `in` statement does not get executed.

If I remove either the nested `in` statement or the `BeforeAfterScope`, the test behaves correctly so I guess I am missing something, but I did not manage to find this out in the documentation.

[EDIT]

In my use case, I am currently populating the database in the `before` method and cleaning it up in the `after` method. However, I would like to be able to have several test cases without cleaning up and populating the database again between each.
What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Scope must be created exactly where you create your example:

```
class FooSpec extends BaseSpec {
  "foo" should {
    "run specs" in {
      "should fail" in new BeforeAfterScope {
        true must beFalse
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**[UPDATE: 10-12-2015 for specs2 3.x]**

Note that if you don't need to inherit values from the `BeforeAfterScope` trait, it is actually simpler to have the `BaseSpec` extend `org.specs2.specification.BeforeAfterEach` and define the `before` and `after` method there.

If, on the other hand, you want to do some setup/teardown before and after all your examples you need the `BeforeAfterAll` trait. Here is a specification using both traits:

```
import org.specs2.specification.{BeforeAfterAll, BeforeAfterEach}

trait BaseSpec extends Specification with BeforeAfterAll with BeforeAfterEach {
  def beforeAll = println("before all examples")
  def afterAll = println("after all examples")

  def before = println("before each example")
  def after = println("after each example")
}

class FooSpec extends BaseSpec {
  "foo" should {
    "run specs" in {
      "should fail" in {
        true must beFalse
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This approach is documented [here](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.6.6/org.specs2.guide.SpecificationTemplate.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just edited my question to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Eric the link is broken

Comment: Yes things have changed quite a bit with specs2 3.x